# js problems cant be added to visual project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'm writing an dot net web site.today i tried to include some JS files but visual studio just hung,tried to add package from package console manager or create them but also did not work.any idea?

Comment: this is completley unclear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I mean i can not add js files in any way and there is no other question like this on web.Do you have any idea on cause of this?